# manually navigate through xamarin master detail project without losing menu functioanlity

Tags: xamarin, menu, navigation, master-detail

I'm trying to understand and figure out how to manually navigate to childpages in a Xamarin masterdetail project, without losing menu functionality.

My situation: I have created a normal MasterDetail xamarin project in Visual Studio 2019, with UWP + Anndroid checked, and ASP.net not checked.
Now this project comes with a filled template.
I added one contentview in the root tree >> a new page.
In App.cs I stated the following:

```
        public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        //MainPage = new MainPage();
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }
```

On this new page I put one simple button.
Now I want to navigate from this normal contentpage (that has no masterdetail menu structure) to a page within the masterdetail.
I've managed to do this by putting the following code behind the button:

```
        private void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newpage = new MenuPage();
        var navigationpage = new NavigationPage(newpage);
        Application.Current.MainPage = navigationpage;
    }
```

This will bring me to the root menupage, the same as an untouched masterdetail template would.
But when I then want to use/navigate through the menu, the project crashes and gives this error:
[image]

I don't know how to solve this anymore, and i'm hoping to get the help here. :)

update: i was able to fix this by doing the following code:    var newmain = new MainPage();  Application.Current.MainPage = newmain;  under the button, and it worked :)

Comment: first, please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Second, you are casting `Application.Current.MainPage` as `MainPage` when it is actually a `NavigationPage`

Comment: @Jason i'm sorry, but i believe i don't understand what you are saying. I've tried to do what they did here: https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-master-and-detail-must-be-set-before-adding-masterdetailpage-to-a-container-44198
That would bring me an error stating that i need to set master and detail first.
On that problem i was struggling yesterday, without succes

Comment: In LoginButtonClicked you are assigning Application.Current.MainPage a value of one type, and in your RootPage getter you are casting it to a completely different type, which causes it to be null.

Comment: @Jason lol, i've solved it, thanks to your answer :)
i did:            
 `code    var newmain = new MainPage();
 Application.Current.MainPage = newmain; `

under the button, and it worked :)

Comment: @Wwes Hi , if have solved that , remermber to update solution in answer . Then other people also will know how to solve that :-)

Comment: yes, i will do that. thnx